# Cookie Consent pop up not showing up on Astro.js Project

Tags: astrojs, cookieconsent

Cookie Consent not showing up on my website: https://mytopcountries.web.app/

`

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
cookieconsent.run({"notice_banner_type":"simple","consent_type":"express","palette":"light","language":"en","page_load_consent_levels":["strictly-necessary"],"notice_banner_reject_button_hide":false,"preferences_center_close_button_hide":false,"page_refresh_confirmation_buttons":false,"website_name":"uspekhi","website_privacy_policy_url":"https://uspekhi.web.app/"});
});

Free cookie consent management tool by TermsFeed Policy Generator

`

I have created an index.html file in the public folder
[image]

I have deployed the website on Firebase, and addded Cookie Consent by TermsFeed https://www.TermsFeed.com
on index.html in the public folder, however it does not pop up on the live page: https://mytopcountries.web.app/

Answer (score 1):

You should not place `index.html` into `/public` folder. It is for your non-code, unprocessed assets (fonts, icons, etc.).

Astro uses `/src` folder for the project files.

Docs: https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/project-structure/